# Understanding output during training - what does the durations mean & what what does TF do between two epochs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, spyder

I am quite new to Tensorflow and Keras and mighty google couldn't help me with the following question so far:

Below you can see TF/Keras-output from training a pre-trained CNN in spyder (using anaconda):

What is those (**bold**) timings about? As far as I could measure, it is the total time needed for this epoch. Am I correct?
The *italicized* numbers mean seconds for the complete batch (steps*batch-size) and time/batch.

What is TF/Keras doing in the significant time-span between two training-batches

Lets look at Epoch 2:
The whole epoch took **42** seconds, the training itself only *7* seconds. What's going on in the remaining 42-7 = 35 seconds?

From my understanding, the training time includes:
+everything about learning (fwd prop, calculating gradients, backwards prop)

Is the remaining time purely loading and re-scaling images?

```
    Epoch 1/50
    50/50 [==============================] - *9s 186ms/step* - loss: 0.6557 - acc: 0.9076
     - **53s** - loss: 0.8610 - acc: 0.8472 - val_loss: 0.6557 - val_acc: 0.9076

    Epoch 2/50
    50/50 [==============================] - *7s 147ms/step* - loss: 0.4148 - acc: 0.9478
     - **41s** - loss: 0.2432 - acc: 0.9097 - val_loss: 0.4148 - val_acc: 0.9478

    Epoch 3/50
    50/50 [==============================] - *8s 158ms/step* - loss: 0.5873 - acc: 0.9384 - **42s** - loss: 0.1696 - acc: 0.9335 - val_loss: 0.5873 - val_acc: 0.9384

    Epoch 4/50
    50/50 [==============================] - *7s 149ms/step* - loss: 0.5356 - acc: 0.9492
     - **41s** - loss: 0.1274 - acc: 0.9548 - val_loss: 0.5356 - val_acc: 0.9492
    .....
```

If it matters: I am using an image generator (see code below) and augmentation. The small (usually <500kb) pics are loaded from an SSD (Samsung 960 1TB).

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    batch_size=20,
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: It contains the time spent on doing the validation and it seems you have many validation images (or a small batch size for doing validation).

Comment: in other words, a lot of the time you see the status bar stalling between epochs is while it's running the validation set. You can also add custom operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers guys, but still I think the feedback does not cover the whole problem. 

Total time used for an epoche: 41sec
Training: 4 sec for 20k pics
Validation:37 sec for 5k pics. 

Does not really seem to make sense so far.